# How to get the number of options and the options list in android?

Tags: android

In my project I need to display the questions and options for that questions. The options for that question are not fixed. For that i have to get the number of options first...so for that I have written the query 
**SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'my_options' WHERE question_id = "+Integer.parseInt(arraylist1.get(0))+"";**   ...here based on the question id the options are displaying. Here I also need to set the options to checkboxes. **How to get both the options and the option count in one single query? Do we need to write 2 different queries for getting the options and options count?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve it using following one query.

this is just an example.

```
Select b.option,count(b.option) from table1 a,table2 b group by b.option having b.que_id = a.que_id and b.que_id = 'your que_id';
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the query....but where should I mention the question id in this query becoz based on the question id I need to display the options...

Comment: so that means your question id is the id pointing to the 'item name' ?

Comment: I have two tables..questions and options. In questions table I have question_id column and in options table i have question _id column. So based on that question id i need to display the options and also the option count...

Comment: Please check it again, I have updated the query according to fetch values from two tables

Comment: Hi I am getting the question id from question table and i am sending that question id dynamically to the query="SELECT options,COUNT(options) from 'options' GROUP BY options having question_id = Integer.parseInt(list1.get(0));...here I want the total numberofoptions that particular question has which is dynamically generated...I executed the query which u gave but it is displaying each option count and not the total count of the options..plz help me regarding this

Comment: can you give me your both table's structure with 2-3 datas please.

Comment: sure, just tell me when you come online, I will tell you that time.

Comment: Hey Sweety, your problem has solved or not  ? if my query was helpful to you then please make favor on me & do upvote my answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Sweety, for the future, anytime you have query just come to this chat room, I am always there http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/

Comment: Hi thank you for the query...it is displaying each option count

Comment: cool, I am happy that I was helpful to you, for live conversions please come to that chat room.